# TypeScript: interface or type with defined attribute names combined with variable attribute names

Tags: typescript

I want a TS type/interface with the following shape:

```
interface Model {
  id: number;
  something: string;
  somethingElse: Date;

  [key: string]: string | null;
}
```

So basically a combination of a defined attributes and 0 - n undefined attributes.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not directly, no.  There are various workarounds, but the best approach would be if you put the undefined attributes in a separate property instead of trying to mix them with your defined attributes.  See [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i) and its answers for more information.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out @jcalz! When it comes to TypeScript you're just the man! =)

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/48422383/5633198

try:

```
type Model = {
  id: number
  something: string
  somethingElse: Date
} & {
  [key: string]: string | null
}
```